# No date, time, and battery icon on Safari toolbar, iPad 17.2

Tags: ipad, safari

I updated my iPad to version 17.2.

Now the Safari toolbar, the bar on the top where the address box is, no longer has the date, time, battery, and Internet icons. The toolbar is now just like in the picture below. How do I bring them back again?

[image]

Comment: Shouldn’t they be on top of the toolbar? Do you see them on the Home Screen?